Issue selecting table in database using oracledb python module and local Oracle 21c database
I installed a local database and used SQL Developer to create a test table.
Database connection works, also the table is created and populated;
example here
Running this example code in Python throws some errors
import oracledb
conn = False
try:
    connection = oracledb.connect(dsn="localhost/xepdb1", port=1521, mode=oracledb.SYSDBA, user="sys", password="syspassword")
    conn = True
    print("connected") # <- this goes to console so it's not a connection issue
except:
    print("failed")
if conn:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM TEST"
    r = cursor.execute(query)

The error I am getting is:

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Now if I create the tables in code, they actually work, but that is not optimal for me since I have to create many tables and populate a lots of data.
Using the SQL Developer interface is so much better for me..
I tried using cx_Oracle package but I find it a bit more difficult to work with and also encounter the same issue while reading data
I tried to change the query to 'SELECT SYS.TEST' or 'SELECT SYSDBA.TEST' and all the case sensitive alternatives
I tried running the selection from command line in sqlplus as sysdba:
SELECT * FROM TEST;

and it display my 2 rows of data
1  test1
2  test4

but python refuses to read the tables for some reason.
It's like oracledb is reading from a completely different database, while sqlplus cmd is in sync with SQL Developer, but tables created in Python are not readable on the other 2 either

NEVER modify the sys or system users - if you modify the system created tables you can corrupt your database in ways that cannot be recovered from. Instead, you should create a different user, grant it the appropriate permissions and create your tables using that user.

With recent Oracle Databases you can connect to either the parent 'root' container database, or a child 'pluggable' database.  Your python-oracledb code connected to the PDB.  Your cx_Oracle code connected to the CDB. Note that your connections strings differ.  One uses the 'service name' xepdb1 and the other uses the SID XE.  This explains why you can't see the tables you are expecting.
The root problems are:

that you are creating objects in the CDB, but you almost certainly should be creating them in the PDB - so your SQLDeveloper connection is 'wrong'. Use a PDB for your own application work.
that you are creating tables etc as the privileged SYS user; instead create a normal user.

If you want to continue using the CDB, then I would suggest going back to python-oracledb, since this is more than two years newer than the final cx_Oracle release.  You can connect to both CDBs and PDBs in python-oracledb - you just need to use the desired connection string.
Also, consider upgrading to Oracle Database Free 23ai which supersedes XE 21c.

So I found a temporary fix,
replaced oracledb module with cx_Oracle
and replaced the connection string with this piece
username = 'sys'
password = 'syspassword'
ip = 'localhost'
port = '1521'
SID = 'xe'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dsn_tns, cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)

now it works when i want to read tables created in SQLDeveloper
